# Time and date in R programming

Tags: r, datetime

please help in

1. Converting number to time format. x <- 0.237314814814815 desired time from this number is 05:41:44 AM.
2. Converting number to date and time format. x <- 44998.79375 desired date and time from this number is 13-03-2023  19:03:00.

Note - Need time as per Indian Standard Time Zone

i tried using as.date, as.POSIXct but unable to get desired result

Answer (score 2):

From your examples, it looks as if times are encoded as decimal days since the start of 1900. In which case you can calculate them using lubridate's `ddays` function:

```
library(lubridate)

ymd("1900-01-01", tz="Asia/Kolkata") + ddays(0.237314814814815)
#[1] "1900-01-01 05:41:44 MMT"

#Or just time
format(ymd("1900-01-01", tz="Asia/Kolkata") + ddays(0.237314814814815), "%H:%M:%S %Z")
#[1] "05:41:44 MMT"
format(ymd("2023-01-01", tz="Asia/Kolkata") + ddays(0.237314814814815), "%H:%M:%S %Z")
#[1] "05:41:44 IST"

ymd("1900-01-01", tz="Asia/Kolkata") + ddays(44998.79375)
#[1] "2023-03-15 19:11:49 IST"
#Not exactly the same due to the rounded number provided, but close
```

Note the slight peculiarity in the first example where you're just getting the time out, that apparently IST wasn't used in 1900, so if you need to pick a more recent year to get the timezone displaying correctly.

Comment: Thank you. this works for me. For getting date and time i modified your formula ymd("1899-12-30", tz="Asia/Kolkata") + ddays(44998.79375) to get exact date.